# How to generate custom signed URL and signed cookies using cloud CDN, storage bucket and LB?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, google-cloud-cdn

It's been two days since I have been working on generating a custom URL to access `cloud storage` private contents.

- I have created CDN and load balancer to access the bucket.
- I have a CDN IP address to access the files.

When I grant a file in `storage bucket` as public I can able to access using CDN IP. Example:
`https://<CDN IP Address>/filename.pdf`

Since all are confidential files I can not make the file as public in my `storage bucket`, so I wanted to use `custom signed URL` and `signed cookies` to generate custom signed URL. I am following `htafoya` answer to generate a custom URL [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52428214/13968434). While doing so I am confused about the `URL` part.
Which URL is should use? Is it `https://<CDN IP Address>/filename.pdf` and followed by `?Expires=1600316057&KeyName=demo-key&Signature=jxkWfkEZ_Jl6OKP83Cf13U-gy-e`? I am getting an error `403` by using the mentioned URL. Does anybody have an idea of how to generate a custom signed URL using `node js`?

**Update**

1. I can able to fix it by recreating everything.
2. It is working only for one file. When trying to access the remaining files browser is throwing `403`.

**Update 1**

I found the problem why it is not working:

1. If any file name contains space, CDN is throwing a `403` permission issue error.

Example:
Working: `https://<CDN IP Address>/filename.pdf?Expires=1600316057&KeyName=demo-key&Signature=jxkWfkEZ_Jl6OKP83Cf13U-gy-e`

Not Working:`https://<CDN IP Address>/network architecture.pdf?Expires=1600316057&KeyName=demo-key&Signature=jxkWfkEZ_Jl6OKP83Cf13U-gy-e`

Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: There should be a `?` after `https://<CDN IP Address>/filename.pdf`, do you have it? There is no Node example in [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls#console_1) but the linked code looks good to me.

Comment: Hi @EmilGi - Thanks for your reply. The complete URL which I am executing along with ? . https://<CDN IP Address>/filename.pdf?Expires=1600316057&KeyName=demo-key&Signature=jxkWfkEZ_Jl6OKP83Cf13U-gy-e still getting`403` error I don't know why

Comment: Are you creating a new signed utl for each file you are trying to access?

Comment: I am trying to access the private  file using `Signature`, `Expires ` and `KeyName `

Comment: Is it a permission problem to the `bucket` level? Assuming because of how come I can able to access one file not the other. BTW I have created a bucket permission level as `uniform` .

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding it a bit. Signed url is created for a distinct file in the bucket, not the whole bucket, so you need to create a new signed url whenever a new file is requested.

Comment: Hi @EmilGi - That's correct!! So what I am doing is whenever trying to access a new file from the bucket I generate a newly signed URL by using the `Signing key` and `Signing key Name`.

Comment: To clarify you generate new signed url for another file and it returns 403?

Comment: Yes, @EmilGi. I don't know why I am getting.